# How to change distance where snap happens in jQuery UI Draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a 100% page height panel that I drag from the left of the page to the right of it. I have applied its snap option and it snaps to left/right sides of the page just fine. Now I need to increase the distance where it happens. Say, I move the panel to 80% of page width from left to right and in that case I want it to stick to the right side of the page.
Is that possible to customize this behavior at all?

Here is how the page looks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the option [`snapTolerance`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-snapTolerance) yet?

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ snapTolerance: 200 });
```

To get 20% in window width, use this:

```
$(document).width() * 0.2
```